# Python Codility Frog River One time complexity

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

So this is another approach to probably well-known codility platform, task about frog crossing the river. And sorry if this question is asked in bad manner, this is my first post here.

> The goal is to find the earliest time when the frog can jump to the other side of the river. 
>   For example, given X = 5 and array A such that:

```
  A[0] = 1
  A[1] = 3
  A[2] = 1
  A[3] = 4
  A[4] = 2
  A[5] = 3
  A[6] = 5
  A[7] = 4
```

> the function should return 6.

Example test:   (5, [1, 3, 1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4])

Full task content:
https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/4-counting_elements/frog_river_one/

So that was my first obvious approach:

```
def solution(X, A):
    lista = list(range(1, X + 1))
    if X < 1 or len(A) < 1:
        return -1
    found = -1
    for element in lista:
        if element in A:
            if A.index(element) > found:
                found = A.index(element)
        else: return -1
    return found

X = 5
A = [1,2,4,5,3]
solution(X,A)
```

This solution is 100% correct and gets 0% in performance tests.

So I thought less lines + list comprehension will get better score:

```
def solution(X, A):
    if X < 1 or len(A) < 1:
        return -1
    try:
        found = max([ A.index(element) for element in range(1, X + 1) ])
    except ValueError:
        return -1
    return  found

X = 5
A = [1,2,4,5,3]
solution(X,A)
```

This one also works and has 0% performance but it's faster anyway.

I also found solution by deanalvero (https://github.com/deanalvero/codility/blob/master/python/lesson02/FrogRiverOne.py):

```
def solution(X, A):
    # write your code in Python 2.6
    frog, leaves = 0, [False] * (X)
    for minute, leaf in enumerate(A):
        if leaf <= X:
            leaves[leaf - 1] = True
        while leaves[frog]:
            frog += 1
            if frog == X: return minute
    return -1
```

This solution gets 100% in correctness and performance tests.

My question arises probably because I don't quite understand this time complexity thing. Please tell me how the last solution is better from my second solution? It has a while loop inside for loop! It should be slow but it's not.

Comment: It is a common mistake to automatically assume that an algorithm with more loops is always slower. Besides, you are not even counting the impliciting loop in `index` (which is `O(n)` since `A` is an unordered array).

Answer (score 3):

Great performance using **set()**

[image]

```
def solution(X, A): 
     
    positions = set() 
    seconds = 0 
 
    for i in range(0, len(A)): 
        if A[i] not in positions: 
            positions.add(A[i]) 
            seconds = i 
     
    if len(positions) == X: 
        return seconds

    return -1
```

Or another solution that has a great performance using **dictionary**

```
def solution(X, A):
    positions = {}
    count = 0
    seconds = -1

    for i in range(len(A)):
        if A[i] not in positions:
            positions[A[i]] = i
            count += 1
            if count == X:
                seconds = i
                break

    return seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer already been told, but I'll add an optional solution that i think might help you understand:

```py
def save_frog(x, arr):
    # creating the steps the frog should make
    steps = set([i for i in range(1, x + 1)])

    # creating the steps the frog already did
    froggy_steps = set()

    for index, leaf in enumerate(arr):
        froggy_steps.add(leaf)
        if froggy_steps == steps:
            return index
    return -1
```

Comment: You can also test for `len(froggy_steps) == x ` in that case instead of comparing two sets, which should be a slight improvement if the two sets are of a significant size.

Comment: The solution seems wrong but passes all the test cases. The `froggy_steps` set should only store value that is less than or equal to X. For e.g. if X = 4 and A = [1,3,5,7,4,2], as far as I read the question the answer should be 5. The above solution returns -1. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution in which you would get 100% in both correctness and performance.

```
def solution(X, A):
    i = 0
    dict_temp = {}
    while i < len(A):
        dict_temp[A[i]] = i
        if len(dict_temp) == X:
            return i
        i += 1
    return -1
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you change the elements of A. Such as, ```X, A = 5, [1,3,1,4,10 ,9,2,3, 5, 4,7]```, output is ```(5, {1: 2, 3: 1, 4: 3, 10: 4, 9: 5})```

Comment: Works perfectly however, another input also fails. ```X, A = 5, [1,3,1,6,4,2,3,4] ``` outputs ```5``` however there is no leaf which in 5th distance.

Comment: I think `if A[i] <= X:` is needed after the while line.

Comment: the question says 
"each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..X]."

Answer (score 0):

The amount of nested loops doesn't directly tell you anything about the time complexity. Let **n** be the length of the input array. The inside of the while-loop needs in *average* **O(1)** time, although its worst case time complexity is **O(n)**. The fast solution uses a boolean array **leaves** where at every index it has the value **true** if there is a leaf and **false** otherwise. The inside of the while-loop during the entire algotihm is excetuded no more than **n** times. The outer for-loop is also executed only **n** times. This means the time complexity of the algorithm is **O(n)**.

Answer (score 0):

The key is that both of your initial solutions are quadratic. They involve O(n) inner scans for **each** of the parent elements (resulting in O(n**2)).

The fast solution initially appears to suffer the same fate as it's obvious it contains a loop within a loop. But the inner while loop does **not** get fully scanned for each 'leaf'. Take a look at where 'frog' gets initialized and you'll note that the while loop effectively picks up where it left off for each leaf.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my 100% solution that considers the sum of numeric progression.

```
def solution(X, A):
covered = [False] * (X+1)
n = len(A)
Sx = ((1+X)*X)/2 # sum of the numeric progression
for i in range(n):
    if(not covered[A[i]]):
        Sx -= A[i]
    covered[A[i]] = True
    if (Sx==0):
        return i
return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimized solution from @sphoenix, no need to compare two `set`s, it's not really good.

```
def solution(X, A):
    found = set()
    for pos, i in enumerate(A, 0):
        if i <= X:
            found.add(i)
            if len(found) == X:
                return pos
    return -1
```

And one more optimized solution for binary array

```
def solution(X, A):
    steps, leaves = X, [False] * X
    for minute, leaf in enumerate(A, 0):
        if not leaves[leaf - 1]:
            leaves[leaf - 1] = True
            steps -= 1
            if 0 == steps:
                return minute
    return -1
```

The last one is better, less resources. set consumes more resources compared to binary list (memory and CPU).

Answer (score 0):

```py
def solution(X, A):
    
    # if there are not enough items in the list
    if X > len(A):
        return -1
    # else check all items
    else:
        d = {}
        for i, leaf in enumerate(A):
            d[leaf] = i
            if len(d) == X:
                return i   

    # if all else fails
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use as much simple instruction as possible.

```py
def solution(X, A):
    if (X > len(A)): # check for no answer simple
        return -1
    elif(X == 1):    # check for single element
        return 0
    else:
        std_set = {i for i in range(1,X+1)} # list of standard order
        this_set = set(A)                   # set of unique element in list
        if(sum(std_set) > sum(this_set)):   # check for no answer complex
            return -1
        else:
            for i in range(0, len(A) - 1):  
                if  std_set:
                    if(A[i] in std_set):
                        std_set.remove(A[i]) # remove each element in standard set
                if not std_set:              # if all removed, return last filled position
                    return(i)
```

I guess this code might not fulfill runtime but it the simplest I could think of

Answer (score 0):

I am using OrderedDict from collections and sum of first n numbers to check the frog will be able to cross or not.

```
def solution(X, A):
    from collections import OrderedDict as od
    if sum(set(A))!=(X*(X+1))//2:
        return -1
    k=list(od.fromkeys(A).keys())[-1]
    for x,y in enumerate(A):
        if y==k:
            return x
```

Answer (score 0):

This code gives 100% for correctness and performance, runs in O(N)

```
def solution(x, a):
    # write your code in Python 3.6
    # initialize all positions to zero
    # i.e. if x = 2; x + 1 = 3
    # x_positions = [0,1,2]
    x_positions = [0] * (x + 1)

    min_time = -1
    for k in range(len(a)):
        # since we are looking for min time, ensure that you only
        # count the positions that matter
        if a[k] <= x and x_positions[a[k]] == 0:
            x_positions[a[k]] += 1
            min_time = k

    # ensure that all positions are available for the frog to jump
    if sum(x_positions) == x:
        return min_time
     return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

100% performance using sets

```
def solution(X, A): 
     
    positions = set()
 
    for i in range(len(A)): 
        if A[i] not in positions: 
            positions.add(A[i]) 
     
        if len(positions) == X: 
            return i

    return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

100% performance using a set

```py
def solution(X, A):
    s = set()
    for i, leaf in enumerate(A):
        s.add(leaf)
        if len(s) == X: 
            return i 
    return -1
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?